# Which of the following is the proper way to implement a callback.

Tags: android, interface

So question. Which of the two is the proper way to do a callback?(Unless both of these are incorrect) Or does it depend on the case.

For example. Let's say i wanted to return something from a Fragment to its Activity.

1)I implement an interface in the Fragment and then on its onAttach I set the listener, and then implement the interface in the activity.

```
public class UrgentCareFragment{

    public interface TestListener {
       void finishedTest();
    }

    TestListener mEventListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_urgent_care_viewpager_fragment, container, false);

        mEventListener.finishedTest();

        return v;
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
      super.onAttach(context);

       try {
         mEventListener = (TestListener) context;
       } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement urgentCareListener");
       }
     }

   /*
    * Deprecated on API 23
    * Use onAttachToContext instead
    */
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   @Override
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
       super.onAttach(activity);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        try {
            mEventListener = (TestListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement urgentCareListener");
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Activity Class.

```
public class testActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TestListener{

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_urgent_care);
  }

  @Override
  public void finishedTest(){
    //do what you need to do
  }

}
```

2) I create an interface class. In the Fragment I set the listener to the activities context by using getActivity. And then implement the interface in the activity.

Interface Class

```
     public interface TestListener {
       void finishedTest();
    }
```

Fragment

```
public class UrgentCareFragment{

    TestListener mEventListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mEventListener = (TestListener) getActivity();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_urgent_care_viewpager_fragment, container, false);

        mEventListener.finishedTest();

        return v;
    }
}
```

Activity Class.

```
public class testActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TestListener{

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_urgent_care);
  }

  @Override
  public void finishedTest(){
    //do what you need to do
  }

}
```

Which is the correct way? My main concern is the way the listener is set. Could either of these two cause issues. Or is there one i should throw out. Both seem to work properly, I am just trying to make sure what the correct way is, or if both are fine.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm. I'm a little confused. Am I not doing the same thing in the first method. Whenever this line is hit,  mEventListener = (TestListener) context. Thanks

Comment: I'm still a little confused. Let's say I used the second implementation in another fragment. Wouldn't I just create another TestListener and then have its activity implement the TestListener? So I'm not sure I'm understanding where I would have cast to a particular activity. Thanks for helping to

Comment: Also, let's say I have a class, Thing, that isn't an activity or fragment. And Thing does some computation and I have a TestListener listenerThing object in Thing. And in Thing I have a method that has a method called setListener that sets the listenerThing . Then in one of my activities or fragment I have a Thing object called thingTest. And this activity/fragment implements TestListener. And in my activity/fragment I do thingTest.setListener(this). Where this refers to the activity/fragment. Is this OK? Thanks